# Bottomnavigationbar cant setcheckable to false but true works fine

Tags: java, android

I have two items, if i alternate between them it will uncheck the other item. But if i click once on a item i setChecked(true); but when i click again i want it to setChecked(false); but that doesnt uncheck the item. ive tried setCheckable(false); and that unchecks the item but then i cant check it again even if i write setCheckable(true) before i setChecked(true).

So the code works for one alteration then since its always checked after that the if statement doesnt work anymore. I can add more code if needed, but feels like im missing some small part.

This is the code

```
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.page_1:

                        item.setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.page_2:
                        if(item.isChecked()) {
                            item.setChecked(false);
                            brushComponent_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        else {
                            item.setChecked(true);
                            brushComponent_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround that gave me the same functionality im looking for, still very strange.

instead of checking the if its checkable or checked and unchecking and that not working. I looked at the visability of the layout and just left the item checked all the time. Visually its a bit ugly but it works which is more important.

```
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.page_1:

                        item.setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.page_2:
                        if(brushComponent_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                            brushComponent_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        else {
                            item.setChecked(true);
                            brushComponent_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```